# Read stream that is modified from outside

Tags: c#, io

I would like to read from a file that can be modified by someone else. Can I easily open a read stream and use a [`FileSystemWatcher`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher.changed%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) to re-read the stream every time it is modified? Or do I have to re-open the stream to the file every time it is modified?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't say how the file can be modified. If it can be completely rewritten, or even set to 0 bytes, then of course you will need to re-read it each time.

Also, if you do so in response to a `FileSystemWatcher` event you are likely to find that it is still in use, and get an IO exception.

To fix that problem you might need to sleep and retry a few times (which is horrible), or you will need to use some kind of synchronisation mechanism with the process that is modifying the file.

However, if you *know* that the other process only ever appends to the file, you could just read the appended data - but you won't be easily able to keep the stream open because once the EOF flag is set for a stream, it will stay set (AFAIAA). Instead, you could keep note of the last-read length so you know where to start reading from.

Comment: Yes, the file will probably be completely re-written every time. My question is: Would I need to re-open the stream every time or can I keep it open and just re-read it?

Comment: @Marnix You'll have to re-open it and re-read it. In fact, keeping it open could cause the process trying to write to it to throw an IO exception.

Comment: I was hoping that such a thing wouldn't happen, because my own process will just be a read process. Maybe I should try and open some sort of socket instead to push the information directly into my process, but I don't know if the third-party process supports that.

Comment: @Marnix If you don't know how the other process will react to the file being open, you'll have to try it and see what happens. I'm guessing it will break...